# Rails 4 app is not writing to production.log , running on Nginx, ubuntu and deployed via capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, logging, production

My app is breaking when customer place an order.

I'm really getting desperate since I need my `production.log` to figure out what is breaking the app!!

I logged into the `:~/mystore/current/log$ nano production.log`

And it seems like the `production.log` haven't been updated since 23/5 2017.

here are the last lines from the `production.log`

```
 I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.067624 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
F, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.069957 #1060] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Label with 'id'=10):
  app/controllers/labels_controller.rb:21:in `set_label'
```

Now I can't see why my app is breaking today. Which is strange because I've always been able to monitor the performance through the `production.log`

this is the settings in the `production.rb`

```
  config.log_level = :info

 config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new('/tmp/foo.log') 
 config.logger.info "SMTP_ADDR: #{ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"].inspect}"
 config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

In the `deploy.rb` I'm sim-linking, don't know if it has any thing to do with this.

```
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/application.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

The app is running on `Nginx` and was deployed via `Capistrano`
 Have anyone had this problem? Can someone help me?

Or maybe more important at the moment: Is there another way to see what is Breaking my app?

Comment: Don't know if it is just a typo in in the example provided but you have the absolute path '/tmp/foo.log' specified as opposed to ' tmp/foo.log'. So you are maybe simply logging to a different place.

Comment: @ulferts  Well this set up has been like this since I deployed the app a year ago,  then I was able to see the `production.log` I doubt this could be the problem, but I'll give it a try and change it

Comment: @ulferts I changed it, It didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem in one of my apps. I couldn't figure the problem out, but then I stumbled upon the `concise_logging`gem https://github.com/gshaw/concise_logging.
And the app started to write to the `production`log.

I would give it a try if I were you. It's very easy to set up and you are ready to go.  Also this post can can be handy http://rubyjunky.com/cleaning-up-rails-4-production-logging.html.